# Why don't the Ashmore twins work on the same projects more often?

Tags: casting, acting

Killjoys stars [Aaron Ashmore](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0039148/) who is the identical twin of the arguably better known [Shawn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0039162/).

Usually, twins in the acting industry end up acting together, either as twins in the same film or TV show, or playing the same part (like the Olsen twins).

IMDb gives a few examples of them working together, mostly in small roles like "man in crowd". Have they ever expressed a reason they don't work together more?

Comment: Any answer to this question would include a list of identical twins who are actors. Unfortunately, we don't allow "list"-type questions on this site. You may be able to reword your question; perhaps you could ask, "What was the first set of identical twin actors who carved out separate acting careers?" You may also want to define how successful they had to be, what film industries (Hollywood, Bollywood, etc.), or more details.

Comment: @Darren Why Shawn is arguably better known than Aaron?!

Comment: Also, I think this is a good question but you should reword it to avoid it being off topic (Why the Ashmores don't act regularly together like most of the other identical twins?)

Comment: @madmada well, he's been in more high profile roles (X-Men for instance). I will try to find time to re-word later, unless someone else wants to.

Comment: Reworded question.

Comment: Because they're terrible actors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just conjecture but I'm going to guess that there's not really a lot of work for twins who are older than five or so (to play the same character). I think the Olsen twins had that locked up in the 90s and everyone got tired of it.

But, think of it... when was the last time you saw a film or TV show that called for identical twins? There were the Mowry sisters in *Sister, Sister*, *The Parent Trap* (played by one person in both versions), The Harry Potter Series (minor characters), *Orphan Black* (one person)... I don't see it often... and with digital capabilities now, it's probably easier to find one actor to play both (or all 6-8) roles than to find actual twins to do it... who are actors... and are equally talented.

Just because they look the same doesn't mean they have the same interests and abilities. Maybe one doesn't want to do comedy because they have no comedic timing... maybe one only likes serious work... it's possible that they'd love to work together if the right project came along. Another explanation could be that their schedules just don't work... if one is on a TV show, they may be unavailable to do a film.

They **have** apparently worked together in more than an extra role on a [2010 episode of *Fringe*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1635958/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_14), though. They play twins Matthew and Joshua Rose on season 3 episode 5, Amber 31422.